# How to fire onBlur event in React?

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, onblur

I have an input field value that I want to format onBlur, here is what my code looks like:

**Component**:

```
  <Input
    onBlur={this.formatEndpoint}
  />
```

**Function**:

```
  formatEndpoint() {
    let endpoint = this.state.inputEndpoint;

    endpoint = endpoint.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/\/+$/, '');

    if (endpoint.slice(-1) === '/') {
      endpoint = endpoint.substring(0, endpoint.length - 1);
    }

    console.log('anything');
  }
```

Why doesn't even the `console.log()` work onBlur? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like its a custom `input`. You should check if the component supports `onBlur`.

Comment: Yes, what does the definition of `Input` look like? Did you write it?

Comment: These comments helped, I just had to add an onBlur prop to `Input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to figure it out. I had to add an `onBlur` prop to `Input` like so:

```
export default class Input extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
  }

  handleBlur() {
    const { onBlur } = this.props;
    onBlur();
  }

  render() {
    return <input onBlur={this.handleBlur} />
  }
}

Input.propTypes = {
  onBlur: PropTypes.func,
};

Input.defaultProps = {
  onBlur: () => {},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

after of a lot of search, I Did that with the follow code,
in my case I am using React CS6.

```
class test extends React.Component {
  onBlur() {
    console.log('anything');
  }


   render () {
      let { onBlur, onChange, value, ...props } = this.props;

      return (
        <input onBlur={ this.onBlur }  />
      );
  }

}
```